# Getting value from HTMLEditor using Jquery in client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I tried ASP.NET HTML Editor from basic tool and need to validate from client side. Client side we used Jquery, So try with element Id with val(),html() . It's not working at that time. Below code we tried,

```
var input = $("#txtNotes_designEditor").contents().val()
var input = $("#txtNotes_designEditor").contents().html()
```

**Update:**

Finally tried below code and it was worked.

`var input = $("#txtNotes_designEditor").contents().find("html").html()`

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Which technology are you using? `I have try a lot` Show us what have you tried.

Comment: I have using Val(), Html() , text() and some function through the internet. but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you said that you've tried using `Val()`.

Don't forget that JS (and jQuery) is case sensitive so try with `$(input).val();`.

Next time copy what you tried to help us.

Comment: yes like that only I have try $("#txtNotes").val() instead of val I am using html, text and some other codes also try. But it's not working

Comment: What does it return or what error does it trigger in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

You've said, it returns nothing.
If it returns nothing that means you didn't fill your input because, otherwise, it would return `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: var input = $("#txtNotes").get()[0];
                var value = input.value;
                alert(value);  I am using this one return empty value. But it's return other values correctly.

Comment: <cc:HtmlEditor ID="txtNotes" Width="885px" runat="server" /> this is I have design, and header <%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" Assembly="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" %> used.

Comment: Have you checked the “make sure” of the answer ?
Suggestions : 
 - Open the console to see what it gives you.
 - Try with another browser.